# Python crashes on console when reading images with OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save an array containing 10000 images, thus I am using OpenCv to load the images. The size of the images is **1280 x 720** pixels, the average size of the images is **30kB**. The problem is that when I reach like 1000 images the program and my computer crashes. I am using Fedora 29, Python 3.6.7 and OpenCv 3.4.4.19

**Code**

```
import cv2


images = []
for i in range(0, 10000):
    print(i)
    images.append(cv2.imread("class_a/" + str(i) + ".jpg"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any traceback of the error? Or are you getting a Segfault instead? Have you monitored your memory usage?

Comment: I don't get any error, it just freezes. I am trying to monitor it now. @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay

Comment: Then it's probably a memory issue, try to load less images. What are your trying to do with such images?

Comment: I am trying to load the images because I am working with a Neural Network. It was a memory Issue thanks! @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay

Comment: It would be helpful to reduce your batch size. Once the model starts training, it requires more memory.

Comment: Woow, thanks for the tip :) @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay

Comment: Your image files may be 30kb on disk but that is the compressed size. With approximately 1 million pixels, that’s 3MB in memory. 10000 images is 30GB. You neglect to say how much memory your PC has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened another terminal and used top to monitor the memory. It seems all my memory went out I the cpu was using my hard drive thus making it slower